# Is there no way to dismiss a timer/alarm with the earpod controls on iPhone that does not result in resuming playback?

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm, audio, ear-phones

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 6. This is what happens:

1. Audio playing in the background OR paused audio playback
2. Timer goes off with alarm sound
3. Dismiss alarm with Earpods center button
4. Playback resumes

I would have thought that after dismissing an alarm sound the phone would go back to whatever state it was in before the alarm, but that doesn't happen in the case of paused playback. This behavior is confusing and seems inconsistent.

Is there a way to turn of the Timer alarm using just Earpods, and without having music playback start?

Answer (score 1):

What I do to stop alarm sound is to **call Siri twice**. First time to stop the alarm itself, second time to stop Siri from listening. This can be done with a very short interval. For reassurance, you can tap thrice each time (in case you tend to miss one of 2 taps required for the command to be registered by AirPods).

P.S. I know the question is about EarPods, but it's quite similar to what some people experience with AirPods. And for EarPods the same could be performed by double-clicking the central button.

Comment: Thank you, I might try that. I'm not familiar with double-clicking EarPods to access Siri though. The double-click action is traditionally mapped to "next song", while a long press is mapped to Siri. Has this changed recently?